# Edit approved list items

Tags: list, permissions, content-approval, item

I have a list here which requires new items be approved. There's a certain field that members would like to edit. When one makes edits, the other does not see. People with approve permissions can see these edits. I don't know that I could create a workflow allowing them to edit items without also automatically approving every item they submit to the list. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would estimate that in the List settings, Versioning settings you need to adapt the last setting, related to who can see draft items by selecting a **Draft Item Security** radio button in the Draft Item Security section. Make sure is set to "Only Users Who Can Edit Items"

This section is disabled unless you allow for minor (draft) versions of your documents or list items.

This will give access to all Contributors to see Draft items, therefore even before being approved. If you also want Visitors to see Draft content (not recomanded) use "Any User Who Can Read Items"

Comment: I'm sorry I left this question for so long. I got busy and couldn't come back to it. Thank you for your answer!